# Service certificate and transportwithmessagecredentials in wcf

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which I want to authentciate using client certificate which I can correctly achieve.My confusion is with securing the data correctly so even if someone intercepts cannot decrypt it.The service runs on https and i am using the below web.config in the service part .The client can be any local worker process or web form or anything.So the question is the below settings the correct way top secure it .

On the client side I configure the service certificate as    `clientChannelservice.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = GetServiceCertificate();` but it does not make a different even if I do or do not provide this service certificate .Jo just wondering that whether I have my service secured correctly or not since when I write the data to the logs I see the return values is not encoded and is transferred as such.Is it because it's protected by SSL or what .If someone can clear my confusion.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior" name="CertProtectedWCF.Service1">
        <endpoint
          address="https://localhost:123/Service1.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding"
          contract="CertProtectedWCF.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="customWsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">           
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehavior">         
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication
                certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
                revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate
              findValue="ACS2SigningCertificate"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Yes, traffic across SSL is encrypted. The message logging takes place after decryption of the request, and before encryption of the response.

Comment: so specifying the service certificate has no effect in this case then.How does the client knows how to decrypt the message when it doesn't even have the certificate.I have a self signed certificate.

Comment: The client will have to be set to trust the self-signed certificate. SSL provides encryption - which your certificate gives you - and identity verification, which a self signed certificate does not provide.

Comment: K nice so basically I have TransportWIthMessageCredential in which SSL cert will encrpyt the message and client certificate validation will validate the client ..but what if I need to validate the service what do I do then or is there no need for that.

Comment: so the thing I wanted a clarification on was that If i don't have the public service cert how is the client gonna decrypt the information the service sends to it.

Answer (score 0):

The client gets the server certificate as part of SSL protocol.  With a self-signed certificate the client cannot verify that they got the right thing by using a CA chain.  But it certainly can use that certificate to decrypt...